# React use form not updating the form default values on api response

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have following component:

```
import { FormProvider, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

  const Test = () => {
    const {
    mutate,
    isLoading: searchLoading,
    data: warehouseResult,
  } = useWarehouseSearchByField();

   useEffect(() => {
        mutate(
      { warehouseCode: warehouseId },{
    onSuccess,});}, 
  [warehouseId]);

console.log(warehouseResult) // Here I am getting the value as well.
                             // But when I am setting it in the formprops
                             // as a default values, it's not setting it up.

const formProps = useForm({
  mode: "onChange",
  defaultValues: {
    warehousename: warehouse?.warehouseName,
    warehousecode: warehouse?.warehouseCode,
    address: warehouse?.warehouseAddress,
  },
});

     <FormProvider {...formProps}>
        <ConfirmationDialog
          isOpen={isEditRoleDialogOpen}
          title="Edit Warehouse"
          content={<CreateWarehouse register={register} />}
          onConfirm={handleSubmit(handleEditWarehouseConfirm)}
          onClose={() => {
            setIsEditRoleDialogOpen(false);
          }}/
          cancelBtnText="Cancel"
          confirmBtnText="Confirm"
        />
     </FormProvider>
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`defaultValues` are set once on component rendering; think of the `useState` `initialState` argument.

There are several things you can do to get the behavior you're looking for.

You can move your form down within the `children` of `ConfirmationDialog` to make sure that the form component where the `useForm` hook gets called is unmounted when `ConfirmationDialog` closes. This way, every time you open the create or update dialog, the `useForm` hook will be called with the new `defaultValues`.

Another way would be to call [the `reset` form method](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/reset) to reset the default values of your form with either the default values of the create form or the entity values if it's an update form, if your default values change.
I don't know your business logic, but it would look something like this:

```js
// a hypothetical data fetching hook
const warehouse = useWarehouse()

const { reset } = useForm({ defaultValues: defaultWarehouseValues })

useEffect(() => {
  if (warehouse) {
    reset(warehouse)
  }
}, [reset, warehouse])
```

Since you're using a data fetching library `SWR`, I can also suggest that you look into the new-ish React Hook Form [`values` API](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#values), which syncs values from external stores (like Tanstack Query or SWR) in a similar way to the way you've described your expected `defaultValues` behavior.

```js
// a hypothetical data fetching hook
const warehouse = useWarehouse()

useForm({ defaultValues, values: warehouse })
```